# Pandas: match on one set of columns and populate with third value

Tags: python, join, pandas

I'm using pandas and trying to fill in the NewManagerId column on the example table below. I've already done a merge and have columns 1-4 and need to append column 5, the new manager ID. The OldManagerId = OldId but then use the NewId value to populate. I've tried a few different approaches and haven't gotten this to work, but I would guess there is a way to do it. Any advice appreciated!

```
OldId   Username    OldManagerId    NewId   NewManagerId
1234    abc1243     4567            987      (need 654)
4567    def134      8798            654      (need 321)
8798    ghi1494                     321      (null)
4687    jkl2957     1234            94       (need 987)
```

Comment: Can you explain further how NewManagerId column should be calculated?  Is it based on an offset of the NewId column?

Comment: please include a sample of the two data frames you are looking to merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a lookup df on a subsection of your df, what we do here is just select the OldId and NewId columns, set the index to OldId. We then call [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) on the df OldManagerId values and this will perform a lookup for the corresponding NewId and set this value:

```
In [12]:

lookup = df[['OldId', 'NewId']].set_index('OldId')
df['NewManagerId'] = df['OldManagerId'].map(lookup['NewId'])
df
Out[12]:
   OldId Username  OldManagerId  NewId  NewManagerId
0   1234  abc1243          4567    987           654
1   4567   def134          8798    654           321
2   8798  ghi1494           NaN    321           NaN
3   4687  jkl2957          1234     94           987
In [59]:
```

Comment: Brilliant! That was exactly what I needed to do. Thanks EdChum!